# LUA Count amount of entries in a table

Tags: lua

I am looking to count how many duplicated i have in my table so if i have a table with:

```
funnyTable = { bread, bike, laptop, bread, lightbulb, bike, bread }
```

I need it displayed as

```
sortedTable = { bread = 3, bike = 2, laptop = 1, lightbulb = 1 }
```

Does anyone have a solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with another table:

```
local funnyTable = { 1, 2, 3, 3 }
local occurrences = {}

for _,v in pairs(funnyTable) do
    if not occurrences[v] then
        -- This is a new element, insert a count of 0.
        occurrences[v] = 0
    end

    occurrences[v] = occurrences[v] + 1
end
```

This outputs `{ [1] = 1, [2] = 1, [3] = 2 }` as expected.

Comment: `occurences[v] = (occurences[v] or 0) + 1` See [lua-users](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExpressionsTutorial) at the **Logical Operators** part or [the lua manual](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html) for why this works